# Lift Curve Converted Into Equivalent Metric

Tags: validation, data-mining

Lift curves allows a modeler to compare different models. This is especially useful when models are in different scales. But this is done by visually inspecting the curves. Is there any equivalent metric which allows the comparison to be done programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the AUC (area under the curve) of the ROC (receiver operator characteristic) curve. This is a more standard measure of algorithmic performance in the data mining community and evaluates to a single number that can be compared across models. There are many machine learning/data mining packages that have the capability of computing this statistic using a simple function call, push of the button, etc.

I imagine you can also compute an AUC for the lift curve, but have not seen or heard of this being done and, as such, would likely require that you implement it yourself. However, because  (to my knowledge) this is not a familiar statistic, the audience to whom you present the results may question why you chose to use it when AUC of the ROC is widely accepted and understood.

Comment: BTW, I forgot to mention the response variable is continuous. Is there any metric similar to ROC/AUC for regression problems?